# How to get the position of button after button click in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have been stuck in the problem from long time.i have buttons in my list view.i am able to handle the click event on button but i am not getting the position of that button due to which not able to retrieve the object of item click.

```
@Override
public View getView(int p, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (v == null) {
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.data, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.button1 = v.findViewByid("button1"); //this is button which i want to handle its onclick to get the position of button
        holder.button2 = v.findViewByid("button1");
        holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
            Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        holder.button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
            Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    }
    return v;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public Button button1;
    public Button button2;
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code? How are you trying to get the position?

Comment: in your case **p** is the position of your button in `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

use **int position** of `item` being `clicked`,

which will help you to perform operation with button, when it is clicked !